# 2 table relation in one record doctrine2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

How to create a record of the two tables in the third to get a table in the third identifier of one of the two tables. Use ORM Doctrine2
[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmS01.png).

Something that now is:

```
// Account.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserCoworking", inversedBy="accountCoworking")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="acoount_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $userCoworking;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserClient", inversedBy="accountUserClient")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="acoount_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $userClient;

// User coworking
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Account", mappedBy="userCoworking")
 */
private $accountCoworking;

// User client
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Account", mappedBy="userClient")
 */
private $accountUserClient;
```

Comment: The description of what you are trying to achieve is very confusing, please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @aferber, thanks from you answer. I want make 2 relations from 2 different tables in one record.[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmS01.png)

Comment: You may not need a reference to User from inside the account. Why not just have separate UserCoworking and UserClient entities and have a manyToOne pointing to Account on each of these. Doctrine recommends reducing bi-directional relationships